# Use and examples of 違う

Tags: meaning

I came across the following kanji on a JLPT N5 vocabulary list: 違う. 違う「ちがう」, is presented as 'different'.  I would appreciate it very much if somebody could present me simple examples of the use of it in the given meaning.  Thank you.

Comment: These two things don't appear to be related, so it's probably best if you don't put them both in the same question.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7SXtyMAg http://pastebin.com/AHbUaxfM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When to use 違う?

You use 違う if you *intend to correct the speaker* about whatever point he conveys.

Example:

> A：ジョンさんはアメリカ人ですか。
>
> B：違います (or 違う, to sound colloquial) 。フランス人です。

Another use of 違う:

When a speaker describes that *two things are different*.

> A: りんごとオレンジは違う果物です。

Hope this helps.

Comment: はい、わかりました。どうもありがとう